# Gitlab CI/CD deploy to local server

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a simple example, but I can't find any solution for this. Imagine we have simple server with Apache2, MySQL, and PHP running services. Also we have installed GitLab.

We have a project with two working directories/repos: Master -> (folder "Production" in `var/www/production`) and the development branch development -> (folder in `var/www/development`).

When a user commits and pushes code from local git to the development branch, GitLab should do a pull request in the development folder on the server. The same situation should happen with the production folder (master branch).

How we should configure our `.gitlab-ci.yml` file for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure gitlab ci to run  the development job when a commit is pushed in the development branch  and to run the production job when a commit is pushed in the master branch

```
deploy-dev:
    stage: deploy
    script:
        - do-something # Deploy to dev
    only:
        - development
```

and for the production

```
deploy-prod:
    stage: deploy
    script:
        - do-something # Deploy to prod
    only:
        - master
```

You still need to edit the script to deploy the files onto your server, probably using SSH.

Comment: Thx, is correct answer. PS: before, we need to add runner service.